# using array to assign css classes to tagcloud

Tags: php, css, arrays, styling, tag-cloud

I am wondering if there are any other approach to do something like this:

```
$classes = array("tag5", "tag2", "tag9", "tag4", "tag1", "tag6", "tag10", "tag8", "tag3", "tag7" );
shuffle($tags); 
foreach ($tags as $tag) { 
    $class = $classes[array_rand($classes)];
    echo "<li><a href='#' class='".$class."'> ".$tag."</a></li>"; 
}
```

The thing is, when I use this approach, the same a.class gets picked multiple times, and some classes do not get picked at all.

I am looking to use tag1 trough tag10, and not picking the same class twice until every 10 has been taken.

Anyone know how I can acchive this?

Thanks for any and all replies!

Comment: isn't shuffle sufficient to randomize the array? it will give you a random order with no repeats

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're already randomizing the order of classes with `shuffle`, there's no reason to randomize them again - just loop through in order

```
$classes = array("tag5", "tag2", "tag9", "tag4", "tag1", "tag6", "tag10", "tag8", "tag3", "tag7" );
shuffle($tags); 
foreach ($tags as $i => $tag) { 
    $class = $classes[$i % count($classes)];
    echo "<li><a href='#' class='".$class."'> ".$tag."</a></li>"; 
}
```

Comment: @Tom: Welcome to SO. Please accept the answer. This will mark your question as answered and is how this site works. See as well: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/147909 - Thanks!